# Difference between TO_[fill in the blank]() and CAST() or CONVERT() in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, type-conversion

I'm taking an advanced SQL course in Oracle and we have been discussing various `TO()` functions for multiple modules. Things like `TO_DATE()`, `TO_CHAR()`, `TO_TIMESTAMP()`, etc.

We then learned about the `CAST()` function which seems to have the same purpose but for a large amount of applications.

What's the difference between `CAST()` and the array of `TO()` functions?

To put it another way, when would I specifically want to use the former over the latter?

Comment: http://sql-plsql.blogspot.in/2010/05/sql-difference-cast-convert.html

Comment: Oh, I put the `CONVERT()` note because I didn't want the question to be referenced to all the previously answered questions comparing them. I specifically was wondering about the `CAST()`. I'll edit my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`to_date`, `to_char`, and `to_timestamp` are functions that exist in the Oracle database.  `convert` is a function that exists in SQL Server.  SQL Server doesn't have a `to_date`, `to_char`, or `to_timestamp`.  Oracle doesn't have a `convert`*.  Different databases will have different conversion functions.

`cast` is an ANSI standard function so it will basically exist everywhere.  But it will generally be less flexible.  You can't specify a format mask for example.

- Technically, as @a_horse_with_no_name points out, Oracle does have a [`convert` function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions034.htm#SQLRF00620).  It just has nothing to do with converting data from one data type to another so it's completely unrelated to the SQL Server function.

Comment: Actually, Oracle _does_ have `convert()`, but it has nothing do with casting. It converts character sets: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions034.htm#SQLRF00620

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - Well caught.  Had forgotten that guy.  Updated my answer.